# Angular (v15) providers for Azure AD are executed before the APP_INITIALIZER promise is resolved

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

We're using Azure AD for authentication, which requires a couple of parameters that we store in a separate JSON file, so we can easily configure it for different organisations. Therefore this JSON file needs to be read before Angular executes the Azure AD initialisation.

I have created a service to do this:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InitializerService {
    public clientId: string;
    public redirectUri: string;
    public tenantId: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public async getAzureAdConfig(): Promise<any> {
        console.log('Getting Azure AD configuration');
        const config: any = await firstValueFrom(this.http.get('./assets/api.json'));
        console.log('Azure ID configuration obtained');
        this.clientId = config.clientId;
        this.redirectUri = config.redirectUri;
        this.tenantId = config.tenantId;
    }
}
```

In the AppModule, we load this with the APP_INITIALIZER provider, so that it should load the values before the other providers:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [(...)],
    imports: [(...)],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: configInitializer,
            deps: [InitializerService],
            multi: true
        },
        (...),
        MsalService,
        MsalGuard,
        MsalBroadcastService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: MsalInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
            useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
            deps: [InitializerService]
        },
        {
            provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
            useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
        },
        {
            provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
            useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
            deps: [InitializerService]
        },
        {
            provide: MatPaginatorIntl,
            useClass: MyCustomPaginatorIntl
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

function configInitializer(initializerService: InitializerService): () => Promise<any> {
    return () => initializerService.getAzureAdConfig();
}

function MSALInstanceFactory(initializerService: InitializerService): IPublicClientApplication {
    console.log('MSALInstanceFactory');
    (...)
}

function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(initializerService: InitializerService): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
    console.log('MSALInterceptorConfigFactory');
    (...)
}
```

The console log shows that the initializer has not loaded the configuration yet before the Azure AD initialisation is executed:

> Getting Azure AD configuration
> MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
> MSALInstanceFactory
> ERROR TypeError: interceptors.reduceRight is not a function
> (...)

How can I make Angular start the other providers *after* `InitializerService.getAzureAdConfig` has resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a dirty workaround, but am still hoping to find an answer and do it the proper way that Angular is supposed to work.

For now, I've wrapped the bootstrapping in an async method to read the config file and save it in *api.ts* before the app itself is bootstrapped:

**api.ts**:

```
export class ApiData {
    public static clientId: string;
    public static tenantId: string;
    public static redirectUri: string;
}
```

**main.ts**:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { ApiData } from './app/api';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

// The client ID, tenant ID, and redirect URI need te be known before bootstrapping the application.
(async () => {
    const file = await fetch('assets/api.json');
    const data = await file.json();
    ApiData.clientId = data.clientId;
    ApiData.tenantId = data.tenantId;
    ApiData.redirectUri = data.redirectUri;

    if (environment.production) {
        enableProdMode();
    }

    platformBrowserDynamic()
        .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
})();
```

The InitializerService (which is now basically redundant) then reads that same file:

**initializer.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiData } from '../api';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InitializerService {
    public clientId: string;
    public redirectUri: string;
    public tenantId: string;

    public async getAzureAdConfig(): Promise<any> {
        this.clientId = ApiData.clientId;
        this.redirectUri = ApiData.redirectUri;
        this.tenantId = ApiData.tenantId;
    }
}
```